# Codeigniter mysql query AND_OR

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just trying to write custom string for `$this->db->where();` function but I get syntax errors. Could you have a look on the code below to find the mistake

```
$where = "'phone' => $this->input->post('phone') AND '2g' = $data['2g'] OR '3g' = $data['3g'] OR '4g' = $data['4g']";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing two types of parameters for the `$this->db->where()` function.

From the docs 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

You either supply an associative array (like `'phone' => $this->input->post('phone')`)
or you suppliy a custom string `$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";`

You can't mix the two

Comment: but what if I don't need to check it like (status='boss') but ('2g' = $data['2g']) ? is there any other way to do it?

Comment: What I think is breaking is the `$this->input->post()`, 
you could achieve the same thing with just adding ` 'phone' = $this->input->post('phone') `